# Define parameter value in script and not in Aginity "Query Parameters Editor" dialog box

Tags: netezza, query-string

I want make a reusable query of the following structure.

DECLARE

DB varchar2(120) := 'Database Name here';

BEGIN

create table DB..TABLE_NAME

.
.

END;

I can do this by making DB a parameter ($DB) but this will prompt for a value during execution time which the person executing the query may not have handy. In other words my question is- how to enter value to a parameter in the script itself and not in Aginity? I don't want end up